# In computer science, what should be the typical author list if it's postdoc's idea and professor's student?

Tags: computer-science, authorship

In computer science (particularly AI), in a project where a postdoc proposes an idea and guides a junior PhD student, and the student does most of the dirty/labor work,  what is the typical author order? Is it one of the following?

- Student Postdoc Professor
- Postdoc Student Professor
- Student Professor Postdoc

Comment: What did the professor do?

Comment: We need an exact topic, as it varies inside CS. Also, is the student a graduate student (i.e., they can use the paper in their PhD) or an undergraduate, what kind of work was it, etc.

Comment: This is why I like alphabetical ordering!

Comment: @OlegLobachev PhD student, see my edit.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot offer a definitive answer, but based on what I have seen it is: Student, Postdoc, Professor.

Comment: In my sub-sub-field of HCI, there is typically one person who writes almost 90% of the paper. If they ran the study, analysed the results, and then wrote most of the paper, they should be first. You can be second, and the professor last.

Comment: I agree with @ThomasKing, in most cases that would be: Student, Postdoc, Professor, but it's hard to devise an all-encompassing rule.

Comment: Why should the professor be an author at all?

Comment: The ethical answer is: only those who contributed will be the coauthors. In your case, I would say "student then postdoc". However, in real life, the professor agreed to be ur supervisor or whatever not because he likes you but because he expects to be a coauthor (even though he didn't contribute). If he gave you a scholarship from his grant, will it is like marriage (he/she will be ur partner in everything).

Comment: If the professor is main supervisor of the PhD project it is customary for him to always be last author in everything you do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, author lists in CS are usually in order of contribution. For practical reasons this often means that you end up with student/postdoc/professor, simply because that's also the order of effort that the various parties can typically put into the project. This would also be my "default" if there are no special circumstances that warrant a different author list.

Some possible special circumstances:

- You, the postdoc, don't only have the idea but also do most of the actual work in the project. In that case it would be warranted to put your name first. However, note that for a PhD student being first author is often more useful than for you, so take this into account when distributing tasks for the project. That doesn't mean that the postdoc should gift the PhD student with first authorship if not warranted, but often it's better for everybody if the project is laid out in a way that the PhD student gets enough tasks so that their first authorship is actually warranted.
- The professor is not interested in the project and does not want to get involved. In this case he *may* not even be part of the project at all and it becomes student/postdoc. **However**, if you want to go for that, make very, very sure that the professor is also ok with not being on the paper. There are many CS labs where the professor assumes to be on every paper that their students write. If you can't live with taking such a professor on, don't work with their students. If you decide to kick off the professor (even if warranted due to contributions), you may not only get into a fight yourself, but you may also make life much harder for the student.

Note that there is in my experience rarely a case where the ordering student/professor/postdoc would be warranted. Actual contributions rarely seem to work out like that, and it's also much less useful for the postdoc than some may think - the postdoc does not become the senior author in the collaboration just because they have been put last in the list.

Comment: "In general, author lists in CS are usually in order of contribution." When an area as large as Theoretical CS orders authors alphabetically, I don't think it makes sense to say "In general, author lists in CS" are anything.

Comment: “There are many CS labs where the professor assumes to be on every paper that their students write” — which, by the way, is *completely unethical*. But it’s become the norm. ☹️

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think the general consensus (based on my experience so far and word-of-mouth), alphabetical orders are common for theory papers and contribution-order in experimental papers. I even remember a "funny" paper a few years back which analyzed the author lists in some 10-15 big CS journals in the last 20-30 years and attempted to comment on how certain subfields have moved from theory to application and back in this span based on the percentage of submissions using alphabetical vs contribution-based order.

Comment: @penelope I'm not sure it's really that simple. AI has a lot of theoretical work that seems to be contribution-ordered.

Answer (score 12):

In my part of computer science (theory), the student and postdoc should be listed in alphabetical order, and the professor should not be listed.

Comment: I think it depends on where you are publishing. For some journals, each author lists his contributions and % of the overall work